# Install4j Wizard Index not showing left panel

Tags: install4j

Using Install4j Version 7

In Pre-activation script for "Directory Selection Screen" I have added the Wizard Index and set Wizard index key [image]

But when I see the Preview for Screen not able to see the Wizard index in Left Panel.[image]

We have a requirement which will show the Wizard index which will show Installation progress. just like below image It will show the current step in bold. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizard index is only shown at runtime, not in the preview. This is because the wizard index is usually not set on the current screen, but on the first screen. Each screen that wants to change the active step just sets a new key for the wizard index. The preview mechanism in the install4j IDE has no concept of screen flow, so its opts not to display wizard indexes at all.

Comment: Thanks, we will try It and share our experience.